# XML Transformation from Java changes namespace prefix to ns1 from nsi

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0, transformation

I have below xslt element which I am using for XML transformation.

```
<xsl:attribute name="{name()}" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </xsl:attribute>
```

However after transformation the XML looks as below

```
<TEST xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns1:nil="true"/>
```

instead of `xmlns:nsi` it changes it to `xmlns:ns1` and for other elements `xmlns:ns0`

Has anyone faced this issue before. when I transform though eclipse output is correct but if I transform it using java code it changes the xmlns prefix with ns0 ns1 etc...

Below is my java code for transformation.

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
javax.xml.transform.Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(sw);
TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

trans.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

After further analysis, when I transform using standalone java program the output is as below(as expected)

`<TEST xmlns:nsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" nsi:nil="true"/>`

but if I run it on server the output is as below

`<TEST xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns1:nil="true"/>`

`xmlns:xsi` is getting replaced with `xmlns:xs1`

Comment: What is the "issue"? Namespace prefixes are not significant: you refer to those declared?

Comment: I have updated the original question. please check the last few lines.

Comment: Please show a minimal but complete XML input sample and a minimal but complete XSLT stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the problem, together with some information which XSLT processor you use (the question is tagged as XSLT 2.0 so do you use Saxon 9?).

Comment: xsi and xs1 refer to the same namespace (in their own documents). The value of the namespace prefix is not important, they are semantically the same namespace declarations. Are you referring to the namespace prefixes somewhere in your xsl (because you shouldn't normally)

Comment: I pass this xml to other system via MQ. And they are referring it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the attribute QName explicitely using the desired prefix instead of using the `namespace` attribute:

```
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:{local-name()}" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     select="."/>
```